# callback and webhook in same file

Tags: json, coldfusion, webhooks, lucee

I have a code where I am sending the callback to the url, like: `http://mywebsite.com/callback.cfm?id=mycardid`

and there is also a webhook provided by the provider which sends the json back for the callbackid

so my first question is:

1. Should I keep the callback and webhook code in the same file or callback in a separate file ?
2. Webhook should be in a separate call because the webhook will not have the mycartid, it will just do a pull from external site based upon the callbackid

I am using coldbox, so I am just wondering, will the HTTPRequestData be available for the webhook and how can I fix it ?

Your suggestions will definitely help me in making a decision how to do it..

Comment: You are push data over as a part of the body of the request?

Comment: i am not pushing data, i need to grab it to save it